# Can Jews say Shabbat Shalom to gentiles?

Tags: shabbat

Shabbat is not a burden, but a blessing.  Gentiles are not allowed to observe Shabbat, can Jews say Shabbat Shalom to gentiles to tell them what they don't have?

Comment: Do non Jews also have to constantly be burning and sewing and cooking so as not to be observing Shabbat for even a moment?

Comment: Interesting question, can you explain what can bé wrong

Comment: @kouty, I have edited question.

Comment: Ok. I understand

Comment: I have seen gentiles as guests in a sleep-over erew shabbat in a rabbi's house. What do you mean, "Gentiles are not allowed to observe Shabbat"?

Comment: @ninamag - It is a commonly accepted position (from the Ramabam) that non-Jews are forbidden from keeping Shabbat (completely). This of course does not mean the non-Jew cannot light candles, have a special Friday night meal, and take off from work, but merely that he's not permitted to keep all of the restrictions. And yet, there are people who argue this with the Rambam.

Comment: I wonder if when we wish each other shabat shalom we mean 'have peaceful rest' or more likely 'have a peaceful day called shabbat' which would mean the question doesn't start. More importantly what do you wish your mechalel shabbos bifarhesya neighbor while you walk to shul and they are out front smoking?

Comment: @ezra thanks for the clarifications. Where can I read more on what Ramba"m said, and where can I read about "people who argue this with the Rambam"? Thanks.

Comment: @ninamag - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13447/is-it-a-discouraged-or-an-unacceptable-practice-for-a-gentile-to-keep-the-sabbat https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20585/why-shouldnt-gentiles-keep-shabbat

Comment: if you're not a jew you just don't keep the whole sabbath, Hashem gave the gift of it only to jews. You can rest, light candles, avoid making tracks, not carrying stuff, no cooking with fire or lghting things, if you want. Then just leave the tp un torn on the roll or squeeze out a sponge or something so as not to do as jews do to make the complete Sabbath.

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with the word "Shabat". However, the Gmara in Gitin ([page 61](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%90_%D7%90)) states that one says Shalom to a Gentile "to be in peace with them" ('משום דרכי שלו).

In Brachos ([page 17](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%96_%D7%90)) it is stated that one should always say Shalom to every person, including a Gentile in the market.

So it seems that the answer is a clear "yes".

However, there is a Machloikes between Rashi and Toisfois in Gitin (there). Rashi states the the Shalom that Rav Cahana said was not meant for the Gentile but for his Rav ("שלא היה מתכוון לברך את הגוי, אלא כוונתו היתה לברך את רבו"). And Toisfois says that it's hard to say such a thing since it is Gonev Daas ("צריך עיון שלא יהא בזה גונב דעת הבריות").

Furthermore, there is a machloikes of the Taz and the Bach on the Shulchan Aruch ([Orach Chaim, 61](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%93)), if the word Shalom is considered Kdusha since it is one of Hashem's names. As a consequence, it would be forbidden to utter it the Beis HaMerchatz etc. And so the Bach tends to forbid saying Shalom with no Kdusha intent and the Taz tends to Lehakel, as when his friend's name is Shalom, in which case according to the Taz he can call him even in Beis HaMerchatz. It would seem that their Mechloikes may apply to saying Shabat Shalom to a Gentile.
The Mishna Beruru says (there) that it is allowed from Divrai Sofrim, but "Yerei Shamayim" should abstain from saying Shalom in such cases.

Comment: "It would seem that their Mechloikes may apply to saying Shabat Shalom to a Gentile." I don't understand why it seems that way.

Comment: @DoubleAA I concur. You only address the concept of using the word "Shalom" in addressing a non-Jew, while the crux of the question is whether gentiles, being ***forbidden*** from observing Shabbos, should be addressed with a ***"Shabbat*** Shalom."

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - there is no problem with the word "Shabat" so I've only referenced "Shalom" and the debate the Poskim had on it. (edited the quetion opening according to your remark)

Comment: @EinbertAlshtein so the possibility that we're encouraging someone to perform a capital crime through their observance of shabbos doesn't register for you?

Answer (score -2):

Why not? It's just silly because they aren't keeping Shabbat. Would you wish a Merry Xmas to a Jewish person sitting in a Chinese Restaurant on December 25th?

Comment: Saying "why not" is not really an answer, is it?

Comment: @EinbertAlshtein Why not? :)

Comment: I might say "shalom" but that's just the kind of person I am. I might say "Shalom" to a person eating alone in a restaurant on dec. 25, chinese, italian, kosher, whstever. Why not?

Comment: I wouldn't say Shabbat Shalom to remind a non jew of what they are missing. Why would anybody do that? maybe op is baiting.