# Can non-Jews say "shalom"?

Tags: blessing, gentiles, shalom-peace

Can non-Jews say "shalom"? I did, two nights ago, spontaneously to some other, I assume, non-Jews. I only did so because I have had it said to me and it felt "cool" to be blessed. I'm not about to tell them I'm not "a Jew" (not unless this is dangerous territory), but I did wonder if it's something I should not do again.

Comment: Sure. I see no problem...other than perhaps coming across as Jewish if you're not.

Comment: Every. Single. Oddball. Question. We get on this site. Starts with "Shalom," ... I still feel like they're calling my name. I also have random people shout out my name when I walk down the street, and wonder if it's someone who knows me. It's not religiously prohibited, but it can get kind of annoying. If you're actually speaking Modern Hebrew and trying to say "hello", fine ... otherwise, Jews speaking other languages don't use it as a freestanding greeting. But if you want to say the Hebrew word for peace because it makes you feel cool? Why not?

Comment: @Shalom Someone told me שלום עליכם. Can you please get off me?

Comment: thank you all for your replies, they were fun. i am severely mentally ill, and can't stick around, due to that. peace :) hah!

Comment: @ezra just say עליכם שלום

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speakers of Modern Israeli Hebrew use "shalom" as a greeting. Really, it's a shortened form of a full, traditional greeting "shalom aleichem" (meaning "peace be upon you").

I don't see why it would be an issue for a non-Jew to use shalom as a greeting, except that it comes across as sort of weird. I actually find it more strange for a non-Jew to use this greeting with a Jew than with a fellow non-Jew.

Imagine seeing a Hispanic person and saying "hola" to them. That's how I feel when random non-Jews say shalom to me. I know they often mean well, but I'm a native English speaker living in the United States. Yes, I also speak Hebrew and Yiddish, but total strangers aren't close enough to me to be delving into my individual cultural heritage. In other words: if you speak English, speak English to me. If you speak Hebrew, speak Hebrew to me. If you speak Yiddish, speak Yiddish to me. I can't tell you how many  times I've responded to a friendly shalom with "Mah shlomcha?" and the stranger stares at me and tells me they don't speak Hebrew. Okay? Then why did you say shalom to me. A plain "hi" is okay.

Comment: 'I don't see why it would be an issue for a non-Jew to use shalom as a greeting, except that it comes across as sort of weird." - your answer would be improved by giving a source. Otherwise it's just you making up a personal opinion.

Comment: @Dude It's my opinion too, and perhaps the logic is, many American Jews like myself almost never greet anyone with "shalom" when speaking English. "Shalom" as a greeting sounds Israeli to our ears, and we wouldn't expect a non-Israeli to use an Israeli greeting.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi David Sperling [answers](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/7845) a similair question (can one say Happy New Year to a Non-Jew?). In his answer, he quotes the Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh De'ah 148:9) with the commentary of the [Shach](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.148.9?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en):

> שלום. כתוב בבדק הבית בשם א"ח בשם הר"ם דוק' שלום שהוא שמו של הקב"ה אבל ברכה דליכא שם ליכא קפידא עכ"ל וכן משמע קצת בפרש"י ומכל מקום צ"ע קצת דבש"ס גבי מקדים ויהיב שלמא וגבי שלמא למר לא משמע לכאורה הכי ושמא שלמא הוי בכלל שלום:

In short:

> The commentators there (see the Shach) discuss whether this law is limited to using the word "Shalom", or all greetings. The ruling is that one may give greetings which do not include the word "Shalom" as it is one of the names of G-d (see for example [Judges 6:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.6.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); note of me), but rather use wording such as "Good Day", "Long Life!", "Good luck in everything" etc. (see Zedah La'Derech, Machon Zomet, p. 197).

So, according to this, it is not allowed (or not encouraged) to say "Shalom", since it is one of the names of G-d. However, this might apply to greetings that can be said during holidays of gentiles.

See also this [thread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85793/27180).

Comment: While this teshuva is interesting, the fact that it's a Jew greeting a non-Jew for a completely different reason likely renders it too distant from the question being asked here to be of much use.

Comment: Personally, I do not think it can get any better than this. It explains why the use of Shalom should be limited on a gentile holiday, since it included one of the Holy Names of G-d.