# Saying "Shalom" to another Gentile

Tags: halacha

Shalom. I believe in the God given meaning of Shalom as a gentile so shalom to you.

What can I use as a greeting, as gentile to another gentile?

Comment: "Greetings, fellow gentile" does sound a tad awkward :) but I'm not sure what you mean by "what can I use"? In what sense? The tag is halacha. It's perfectly halachically sound to say "hello". It sounds like you are asking if it's ok for a non-Jew to say "shalom" to another non-Jew, or if not, what's the closest equivalent? What's the basis for your question? Does this help? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/132451/31534

Comment: I think it will depend on what language you're speaking. "Buenos días" sounds great in Spanish (particularly in the morning) but less great in Thai.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Josua and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Well since a gentile has no promises without Israel would saying "May the blessings of Israel find you" be acceptable or is it too much?